# What's the meaning of "б" on its own?

Tags: буквы

The song Подмосковные вечера a **"б"** used on its own:

Если ***б*** знали вы, как мне дороги

What does this mean?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's short for бы, used in conditional constructions.

Comment: roughly equal to "would"

Comment: @CocoPop - Will you please make that an answer, not just a comment?

Comment: @YellowSky: My answer is too simplistic and I'm not a native - I think Nikolay's answer says it all :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`б` is a variant of `бы` that can be used (entirely optionally) if the preceding word ends with a vowel. `Чтобы`, being `что`+`бы`, always has the variant `чтоб`.

Similarly (with the same after-a-vowel rule), `ли` has `ль` and `же` has `ж`. The full and shortened forms are not entirely interchangeable; the shortened ones are stylistically non-neutral in most contexts, so when in doubt, use the full ones. You'll come across the short ones a lot in songs and poems, though, because they're a convenient way to lose an extra syllable.

Comment: About shortened syllables in songs & verses. Sometimes poets use too many of them, which is considered to be a bad style. This issue is unformally referred as "ужи" - the plural of "уж" which means both Natrix snake, and the shortened form of "уже" (already).

Comment: @user4419802 that, I'd say, is the opposite phenomenon — throwing in semi-meaningful monosyllables as filler, which of course sounds awful but is not related, per se, to уж and similar contractions. Лишь is another all-time favourite with bad poets, and it's not a shortening of anything.

Answer (score 0):

sorry cannot comment yet.

"б" is a short form of "бы", which is used in conditional constructions.

"Если **б** знали вы" means "If you knew."

I think it's just the way it sounds. The tension goes on "бы" and breaks the rhythm.
With "б" there is no tension in the middle of the sentence:
"Если **б** знали вы" = "Если **бы** вы знали" = "Если **б** вы знали" (less common)

I would compare it to "if you knew" vs "If you **only** knew"

Comment: Sorry, but "If you would know" is not correct English, you should say "If you knew". Never use "would" or "will" after "if" or "when."

Comment: my bad :) thank you.<br/> btw, "would" can be used as a polite request. Example:  "if you would like"